# Generalizing slick update to N columns

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I created a generic method to update the value of a column in a Slick table. All my tables extend from a common trait that has an `id` so it was easy to come up with something like this:

```
  def update[T](id: Long, targetColumnSelector: SimpleTable => Column[T], value: T): Boolean = {
    db.withSession {
      self.filter(_.id === id).map(targetColumnSelector).update(value) > 0
    }
  }
```

And invoke like this:

```
MyTable.update(obj.id, _.field, fieldValue)
```

Now I wanted to generalize this to update multiple columns at once. It's easy to make it for 2 columns, but how to make it so that I can use a tuple of any size? I am using Slick 2.0

```
  def updateTuple[B, C](id: Long, targetColumnSelector: SimpleTable => (Column[B], Column[C]), value: (B, C)): Boolean = {
    db.withSession {
      self.filter(_.id === id).map(targetColumnSelector).update(value) > 0
    }
  }
```